# Remove glue residue after sticker removal

Tags: paint, decals

After removing a sticker from frame I have layer of glue residue left that can't be removed even when using brake cleaner or WD-40. Only scrubbing for 10 minutes nonstop removes it. Is there an easier way to get rid of that residue without damaging the paint job?

Comment: You can try other solvents (alcohol, acetone,...). Check it does not affect your fraim paint first.

Comment: Duct-tape, rubbing it on, pulling it off just after that, repeat several times. Strangely enough it works.

Comment: There is a commercial product for this, but I don't recall the name

Comment: Not really looking for chemical solution especially commercial. I find that heating the surface with torch or blow drier makes removal with rug easier, but still too much effort required. perhaps it can be frozen and then scraped off with ATM card or smth similar, i got to give this a try, but for all other surfaces than flat its still a challenge. 

@Carel Thanks i will try duct-tape.

Comment: Un-du is commonly used for this but I've found that WD-40 works almost as well.  Find Un-du at craft and hobby stores.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Perhaps Goo Gone is what you're thinking of?

Comment: @Armand - No, it's something else

Comment: De-solv-it is a commercial product. I have often found soaking in cooking oil (overnight)

Comment: Are you sure its gluie, and not clearcoat paint?  It is not uncommon decals/stickers to be put under a layer of paint.

Comment: Its under the sticker not on top so its glue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My friend's father used a dab of petrol (from the lawnmower can) on a cloth rag for this scenario and the glue residue wiped right off, no effort.

It smells and is flammable but is a good, easy solution that you might think is worth a go.

Comment: Petrol contains, amoung other nasties,  Benzene, a carcinogen with no known safe limit.  Naptha (aka Shellite/White Petrol depending where you live in the world) will probably work where Petrol does and is far safer.

Answer (score 2):

Heat guns and even hair driers are [known](https://www.drsticker.nl/en/blogs/nl/how-to-remove-stickers/) as capable of removing stickers. Of course, this would heat the surface. Likely not a problem for a metal frame but generally think where are you applying.

Answer (score 1):

If it is indeed a resedue from the sticker adhesive and none of the chemical products help, try heating it up with a hairdryer then rubbing/rolling it off with a rough cloth.

Comment: This was my original solution takes forever to remove, perhaps if heat more is okay, but i dont want to damage paint.

Answer (score 1):

[De-solv-it](https://www.hipac.net.au/cleaning/de-solv-it/) removes anything, I had nail polish on my couch from my niece, only desolvit saved  the day, I use it on every stain with little scrubbing required :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Is this actually safe for the paint job?

Answer (score 0):

I've got some stuff called "sticky stuff remover" which I use for jobs like this. I got masses of duct tape sticky off car bodywork once.

You can get it in B&Q amongst the usual suspects I think.